# Java Array is not being filled correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code that I can't seem to debug. I am adding an object `passenger` into a `seat` object that is in a `row` object. If a`seat` is occupied it will start from the first `row`, go through all the `seats` and add a `passenger` to it. However if I `remove` a previously owned `seat`, then add a new `passenger`. The new `passenger` should occupy the previously owned `seat`. This is not the case, the new `passenger` will occupy the next `seat` instead. My assumption is that my `firstClassRow.get(i)` is starting at the most recent `index`, rather than 0.

Here's just a basic example

```
1A filled 1B unfilled(should fill here)
2A filled 2B filled
3A filled 3B unfilled(but fills here)



public void addUser(Passenger p)
{
    Rows tempR;
    boolean result = true;
    int i = 0;


    while(result == true)
    {
        tempR = firstClassRow.get(i);
        if(tempR.check(p) == true)
        {
            tempR.addPassenger(p);
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 1;
            if (i < number)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why does `tempR.check(p)` return false for the first row?

Comment: `tempR.check(p)` checks the seats in the row for an available seat comparing the name `attribute` of `passenger` object. so if `check(p)` is true, a seat is available. add, then break out of the `while` loop by returning false and go on to a new passenger

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Yes, `int i` remains at whatever updated value, instead of restarting at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example may be helpful

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String ll[][] = new String[2][2];
    System.out.println(ll.length);
    System.out.println(ll[1].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < ll.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ll[1].length; j++)
            ll[i][j] = "true";
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("All seats are occupied");
    display(ll);
    ll[0][1] = "false";
    ll[1][1] = "false";
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Two seats emptied");
    display(ll);
    // adding new one
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Adding new passenger");
    addPassenger(ll);
    display(ll);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Adding new passenger");
    addPassenger(ll);
    display(ll);
}

static void display(String a[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a[1].length; j++)
            System.out.println(i + "" + j + " :: " + a[i][j]);
}

static void addPassenger(String a[][]) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a[1].length; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == "false") {
                a[i][j] = "true";
                result = true;
            }
            if (result)
                break;
        }
}

 Output:
 All seats are occupied
 00 :: true
 01 :: true
 10 :: true
 11 :: true

 Two seats emptied
 00 :: true
 01 :: false
 10 :: true
 11 :: false

 Adding new passenger
 00 :: true
 01 :: true
 10 :: true
 11 :: false

 Adding new passenger
 00 :: true
 01 :: true
 10 :: true
 11 :: true
```